# Javascript InnerHTML is a scriplet code displaying as a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, scriptlet

I am using javascript innerHTML to post some data from javascript. Please find the below code:

```
var innerHTML='<% SomeClass.getSomething %>';
document.getElementById("something")=innerHTML;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="something"></div>
```

Now i am able to see the output as `<% SomeClass.getSomething %>`. But how do i render it to show the value of getSomething. Please Help.

The SomeClass is defined in jsp where the html is there.

Comment: There isn't enough context for this. Where is `SomeClass.getSomething`? Is it a global variable in the javascript? Is it something from some template engine you're using?

Comment: Please see how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us help you.

Comment: @TKoL that class is in the jsp where the html is there.

Comment: I know a fair bit about javascript and not a lot about JSP, but it seems like you're trying to access the value of a *server side variable* with a *client side script*. That's what it looks like to me. If that is the case, then you need to have some way of passing the value of `SomeClass.getSomething` from the server to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is in a JSP file I think you want the following

var innerHTML='<%= SomeClass.getSomething %>';

The <%= tells the JSP to output the expression in place.

Comment: No its in a seperate JS file @Deadron. Thats where the issue is now.

Comment: You can't execute JSP scriplet tags in a JS file. Write the value inside your JSP file somewhere and then pass it into your JS file as a function param.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   var innerHTML='${SomeClass.getSomething}';
```

If you are passing it througn model.